# Отправка сообщения из websocket сервера при выполнении функции

Tags: python

Мне удалось реализовать веб сокет сервер исходя из примеров в интернете.

```
import asyncio
import websockets
def test():
  #тут отправить сообщение
    retern 0
async def echo(websocket):
    async for message in websocket:
        await websocket.send(message)

async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(echo, "localhost", 8766):
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever

asyncio.run(main())
```

Как можно сделать отправку сообщения всем клиентам при вызове функции test?

Comment: На входе в echo сохраняете в каком нибудь массиве все полученные соединения. На выходе - удаляете завершенные соединения из этого массива. Имея на руках этот массив можно рассылать не нему всем сообщения

Comment: я добавил в массив websocket. и пытаюсь отправить таким образом websocket[0].send("hello") но оно просит async, не совсем понимаю как это реализовать

Comment: конечно ваша test должна быть с async и отправку надо делать с await, хотя бы отложенным